# initial array of struct using fread

Tags: c

I have a struct of students that written to a file all what I want is initial the array with values from the file using any method, the aim is to put the struct values into array to help sorting process the code gives me punch an kick any idea how to achieve it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
struct student
 {
  char  id[5];
  char  name[30];
  int   term;
  float gpa;
  char  grade;
 };

struct student stu;

typedef struct student stud;


int main ()
{
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("record.txt","ab+");
char nextChar = getc(fp);
int numCharacters = 0;

while (nextChar != EOF)
{
    numCharacters++;
    nextChar = getc(fp);
}
//////// detect number of characters ////////

int chunck = numCharacters/sizeof(stu);

stud *arr = (stud *)malloc(chunck);

/*//problem comes next ...
// intial the array of students with records from file
while(fread(&stu,sizeof(stu),1,fp) == 1)
{ 
  for(d=0;d<chunck;d++)
  {
   arr[d].id=stu.id;
   arr[d].name=stu.name;
   arr[d].term=stu.term;
   arr[d].gpa=stu.gpa;
  }     
}*/

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better use `fstat` to get the length of your file. It does not position the read cursor at the end of your file, so you don't need a `rewind` (which is what you seem to be missing).

Comment: After detecting the number of bytes in the file (btw, you could use `fseek` and `ftell` for that), you need to allocate `chunck *sizeof(*arr)` bytes. Then, when you read the actual data, the file must be set to read from the beginning again with `fseek`. It's also better to make `d` run to `chunck` and check for read errors outside the loop condition.

Comment: write a number of records at the beginning of the file.

Comment: could you be more specific as you see i have already know the size of my file and how many characters in it and divided it on the size of the struct to get the number of records in it ,,, simply i cannot intial the array with data from file ... i got stucked in the how matter

Comment: could you post a code solution for this trap

Answer (score 0):

Need to place the cursor to the starting of the file again before u read and initalize ur `arr struct`.

As mentioned in the comments ----> use `fseek` or `rewind`